# Why can't I update conda?

Tags: conda

I'm trying to update `conda`, as per its own suggestion, but I'm getting this:

```
% conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda
Channels:
 - conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: osx-arm64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
    current version: 23.11.0
    latest version: 24.1.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use Conda install to be specific

Conda will be forced to explain itself if you ask more specifically:

```bash
conda install -n base 'conda>=24.1.0'
```

<sub>**Note:** Personally I would use `mamba` here because it is far better at conflict reporting.</sub>

Otherwise, contrary to user expectations, **the `conda update` command does not tell Conda to install the *absolute* latest version of a package**. Rather, it tells Conda to install the latest version *that is compatible with the other environment constraints*.

---

#### Additional Details

Most likely there are underlying conflicts with some other installed packages which prevents updating the `conda` package. This could be because the user has either explicitly (using `conda-meta/pinned`) or implicitly (by request a specific version in `conda install`) *pinned* some other package to a version that is not compatible with updating `conda`. Or, there could be a package that has a shared dependency with `conda` and that package has not been built against the version of the dependency that the newer Conda was built with.

Comment: Did you mean the command line should be:
mamba install -n base 'conda>=24.1.0'

Comment: @Yifangt sure, if you'd like a better report about the failure. However, there was recently some lag between Mamba and Conda releases such that having `mamba` installed in the **base** was literally the reason for why the latest `conda` couldn't be installed. This has probably been resolved now, but it was the case a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. What gave me a clue to the problem was, as mentioned above, run the upgrade command with the specific conda version.  The command did not work, but it gave me this output (truncated because full output is very long - see below).  This pointed to a conflict between my python version (which is pinned), new version of conda, and my installed version of mamba (v1.5.6). I uninstalled mamba and ran conda update which worked. But now if I want to reinstall mamba, it wants to revert back to the older conda (23.11.0). So, the conflict is with mamba and conda (for me at least).

```
warning  libmamba Added empty dependency for problem type SOLVER_RULE_UPDATE
Could not solve for environment specs
The following packages are incompatible    
├─ conda 24.1.1**  is installable with the potential options
│  ├─ conda [22.11.0|22.11.1|...|4.14.0] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.10,<3.11.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda [23.10.0|23.11.0|23.9.0|24.1.1] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.12,<3.13.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda [22.11.0|22.11.1|...|4.9.2] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.8,<3.9.0a0 , which can be installed;
│  ├─ conda [22.11.0|22.11.1|...|4.9.2] would require
│  │  └─ python >=3.9,<3.10.0a0 , which can be installed; 
...
```

Comment: Yes, there was a compatibility issue with `mamba` and the latest `conda` - expect it will eventually resolve and just use whichever one you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

### Using the --all option unpins, and updates all packages to their latest versions

I was experiencing this same issue and came across this in [the documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/update-version/):

> conda update --all will unpin everything. This updates all packages in the current environment to the latest version. In doing so, it drops all the version constraints from the history and tries to make everything as new as it can.

Changing the command line to be:

```
conda update -n base -c conda-forge --all
```

Made it work just fine and update all the necessary pieces. This includes conda 24.1.1, python 3.12.2 and libmamba 1.5.6 (with the 24.1.0 solver). So, really everything as of today.